# foreach loop in array value in only last value print

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have get foreach loop in month and total month value count data in array print  but only last value print in array

```
foreach($rawData as $Data)
{
    $monthsss = $Data['month_no'];

    if($monthsss=='1')
    {
        $arrayF['jan'] = $Data['month_count'];
    }
    else
    {
        $arrayF['jan'] = '0';
    }

    if($monthsss=='2')
    {
        $arrayF['feb'] = $Data['month_count'];
    }
    else
    {
        $arrayF['feb'] = '0';
    }
 }
```

Comment: Where is the loop in the code, please add the complete code.

Comment: Can you explain what you're getting at here?

Comment: Please show input and expected output.

Comment: Your logic is flawed. For example: in your loop, if `$monthsss=='1'` and you set `$arrayF['jan']`, it will still be set to `0` in the second else block. Instead, create the array with all the months and set the values to `0` before the loop. Then in your loop, remove all `else`-parts.

Comment: @ Magnus Eriksson, ok thank it's work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please modify your code as follows

```
foreach($rawData as $Data)
{
    $monthsss = $Data['month_no'];

    if($monthsss=='1')
    {
        $arrayF['jan'] = is_null($Data['month_count'])? 0 : $Data['month_count'];
    }


    if($monthsss=='2')
    {
        $arrayF['feb'] = is_null($Data['month_count'])? 0 : $Data['month_count'];
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

When someone comments and asks *Please show input and expected output.* this is not done to give you more work, but there are many ways to achieve what you want but many answers can be wrong or require much more code (as with the accepted answer).

**Presuming this is your data:**

```
$rawData = [
    ['month_no' => 1, 'month_count' => 1],
    ['month_no' => 2, 'month_count' => 1],
    ['month_no' => 3, 'month_count' => 1],
    ['month_no' => 4, 'month_count' => 1],
    ['month_no' => 1, 'month_count' => 2],
    ['month_no' => 6, 'month_count' => 2],
    ['month_no' => 7, 'month_count' => 6],
    ['month_no' => 12, 'month_count' => 4],
];
```

**Do you want just the summed up values?**

```
<?php

$array = [];
foreach ($rawData as $data) {
    $m = strtolower(DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $data['month_no'])->format('M'));
    $array[$m] = !isset($array[$m]) ? $data['month_count'] : $array[$m]+$data['month_count'];
}

print_r($array);
```

https://3v4l.org/vXgCL

```
Array
(
    [jan] => 3
    [feb] => 1
    [mar] => 1
    [apr] => 1
    [jun] => 2
    [jul] => 6
    [dec] => 4
)
```

**Or do you want an array of all the months with the summed up values:**

```
<?php

$array = [];
foreach (range(1, 12) as $month) {
    $m = strtolower(DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $month)->format('M'));

    $monthSet = array_filter($rawData, function ($v) use ($month) {
        return $v['month_no'] === $month;
    });

    $array[$m] = 0;
    foreach ($monthSet as $data) {
        $array[$m] += $data['month_count'];
    }
}

print_r($array);
```

https://3v4l.org/vqnnv

```
Array
(
    [jan] => 3
    [feb] => 1
    [mar] => 1
    [apr] => 1
    [may] => 0
    [jun] => 2
    [jul] => 6
    [aug] => 0
    [sep] => 0
    [oct] => 0
    [nov] => 0
    [dec] => 4
)
```

**Or perhaps don't even care about the month's strings as your comment suggests.**

```
<?php
$array = [];
foreach ($rawData as $data) {
    $m = $data['month_no'];
    $array[$m] = !isset($array[$m]) ? $data['month_count'] : $array[$m]+$data['month_count'];
}

print_r($array);
```

https://3v4l.org/7gKRo

```
Array
(
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 1
    [6] => 2
    [7] => 6
    [12] => 4
)
```

Its why we ask..